# Getting specific dates from a date range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a sheet that have a range of dates in column A. I already found the way to get the last row with:

```
LastRow = Worksheets("TIME").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Now I am trying to get specific dates. The range contains no weekends, but since the dates are proprietary, I could not use the WorkDay function to find what I need.

### Case 1:

From the last date available, I am trying to get the date 1 year before (if the date is not available, pick the next available one).

What I did here was to use the date function and subtract 1 year..

```
day1Y = date(year(LastRow)-1,month(LastRow),day(LastRow))
```

To match, I transformed the date range into an array, and used a function do determine if it is in the array. If it is, get it, but if it is not, I don't know how to get the next available.

```
Dim DateArray() as Variant
Dim WantedDate1 as date
Dim WantedDate2 as date
DateArray() = Worksheets("TIME").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value

If IsInArray(day1Y) = True then
WantedDate1 = .Cells(1,LastRow).Value
End if
```

### Case 2:

From the last available date, I am trying to get the first date in the same year (if last date is 10/08/2015, it gets the first available date of 2015, according to the dates available in the range).

```
WantedDate2 = Year(.Cells(1,LastRow).Value)
```

I got the year of the last date, but again, I can't find the first date of that year.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: to get the `LastRow` fully qualify your code, use `LastRow = Worksheets("TIME").Cells(Worksheets("TIME").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: That part of the code is already working fine for some reason. Problem is getting the right dates.

Comment: Try to use the built-in Date function in VBA, use `DateAdd`, in your case use `day1Y = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, LastRow)` , it will subtract 1 year from the date value in your variable LastRow

Comment: I don't understand "proprietary" and how does that stop you using the WORKDAY function?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I meant that the dates are not as in the normal calendar. (the one which VBA access with the workday function). The dates are given based on some pre-defined rules, so some weekdays are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop to increase the days 1 by 1 and test if it is the array on the go :

```
Option Explicit

Sub DGMS89()
    Dim wsT As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Double
    Dim DateArray() As Variant
    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim Day1y As Date
    Dim WantedDate1 As Date
    Dim WantedDate2 As Date

    Set wsT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TIME")
    LastRow = wsT.Cells(wsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    DateArray() = wsT.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value

    LastDate = DateArray(UBound(DateArray, 1))
    Day1y = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, LastDate)

    WantedDate1 = Day1y
    If IsInArray(WantedDate1) Then
    Else
        Do While Not IsInArray(WantedDate1)
            WantedDate1 = DateAdd("d", 1, WantedDate1)
        Loop
    End If

    WantedDate2 = DateSerial(year(LastDate), 1, 1)
    Do While Not IsInArray(WantedDate2)
        WantedDate2 = DateAdd("d", 1, WantedDate2)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: One question regarding the do loop: don't I have to state the result of the function value (true or false)?

Comment: You can but it is not necessary as it already a boolean, so if you just return True or False, you don't need to (same thing for `If`)! ;)